# Issue with html table in laravel 5

Tags: html, laravel

I have a table in a blade file.

```
<table style="width:80%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Issue</th>
    <th>Entry Type</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  @foreach($issues as $issue)
    <td>{{ $issue->code }}</td>
    <td>{{ $issue->type }}</td>
    <td>{{ $issue->issue }}</td>
    <td>{{ $issue->entry_type }}</td>
    <td>{{ $issue->value }}</td>
  @endforeach  
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, it dispays like this:

```
Code    Type    Issue   Entry Type  Value
ABC RMK UDID 67 list    ABC-U67 ABC RMK UDID 43 list    ABC-U43
<
```

It's not only displaying two record across one row but also displaying a left angle bracket which I can't find in the code. Any help would be appreciated. I am new at Laravel.

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with your html, not laravel.
The `<tr>` tag should be in the `foreach`.

Here:

```
@foreach($issues as $issue)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $issue->code }}</td>
        <td>{{ $issue->type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $issue->issue }}</td>
        <td>{{ $issue->entry_type }}</td>
       <td>{{ $issue->value }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I think you meant <tr> not <li>.

Comment: Yeah, sorry it was the `<tr>` tag

Answer (score 1):

It should be like

```
<table style="width:80%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Issue</th>
        <th>Entry Type</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($issues as $issue)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $issue->code }}</td>
            <td>{{ $issue->type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $issue->issue }}</td>
            <td>{{ $issue->entry_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $issue->value }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you guys! It works perfectly. I also found my left bracket hidden in the code. Again, thanks.